# Convert kinetic rate constant into a rate?

Tags: kinetics

Can anyone tell me how I can convert a rate constant derived from first order kinetics (units are $\mathrm{h^{-1}}$) into an actual rate (turnovers/h)?

The scenario is that I know my rate constant for a molecule degrading in solution and it is $0.012\ \mathrm{h^{-1}}$. I know that I have $10^{14}$ catalyst molecules in the solution. How can I translate that into a number of molecules converted  per catalyst per hour?

Comment: What approaches have you considered so far?

Comment: Okay, I think I have it. The key is to recognize that the rate constant in units of hr^-1 was for the entire solution, and I can just multiply the rate by the number of molecules that I start with and divide by the molecules of catalyst. Factor label method to the rescue!